# Is there any book for upgrade to java se 7 programmer certification exam?

Tags: java, scjp, ocpjp

I need help. I want to appear for upgrade to java se 7 programmer certification exam. While searching on net, I found this..
[Oracle Tutorial for upgrade to java se 7 certification](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/extra/certification/javase-7-upgrade.html)

Is there any book for the same?

Thanks

Comment: You can visit [this](http://www.epractizelabs.com/certification-advisor/time-estimator.php) site to estimate how much time it will take to be prepare for you exam. Best of Luck for your exam :)

Comment: Thaks Mr Pandey. It showed me some number of hours to prepare for the exam but I want to know if there is any book for upgrade exam or not..

Answer (score 2):

Manning have good oca 7 certification books

http://www.manning.com/gupta/

And a pre-order for advanced version

http://www.manning.com/gupta2/

Comment: Thanks a lot for your reply. But I want to appear for Upgrade exam i.e. 1z0-805 .

Comment: I don't think you would get a book specifically for upgrade. Both exams will be relatively same only with some filtering of topics. You have the topic list in the link mentioned and you could use this book to learn those topics alone for your exam. This book could generally be used for both exams (1Z0-803 and 1Z0-805).

Answer (score 2):

There's no official certification book which contains all topics for OCPJP 7. So, As of now, you are on your own. See [this](http://java.boot.by/ocpjp7-upgrade/) note, this might help you. Although I can suggest below two books.

[Oracle Certified Professional Java SE 7 Programmer Exams](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1430247649)

[OCA/OCP Java SE 7 Programmer I & II Study Guide](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0071772006)

Answer (score 1):

I think this is the book you are looking for this may help you alot for exam [OCP Java SE 7 Programmer](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0071772006)